# Appending to Pandas DataFrame with categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas

How do I append to a Pandas DataFrame containing predefined columns of categorical datatype:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['a','b'])
df['a']=pd.Categorical([],categories=[0,1])

new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[1],'b':[0]})
df.append(new_df)
```

The above throws me an error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Update:
if the categories are strings as opposed to ints, appending seems to work:

```
df['a']=pd.Categorical([],categories=['Left','Right'])

new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':['Left'],'b':[0]})
df.append(new_df)
```

So, how do I append to DataFrames with categories of int values? Secondly, I presumed that with binary values (0/1), storing the column as Categorical instead of numeric datatype would be more efficient or faster. Is this true? If not, I may not even bother to convert my columns to Categorical type.

Comment: Should this work? new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[1],'b':[0]}),
new_df['a'] = new_df['a'].astype('category')

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work, but Anwar's answer below does. It throws the error ``incompatible categories in categorical concat`` and the issue has been reported here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12699
I think the issue is that categories in the ``new_df`` are not fully defined and hence may not be consistent with the categories in ``df``

Comment: You probably want to use union_categoricals:  somewhat similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639350/retaining-categorical-dtype-upon-dataframe-concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the both data frames consistent. As you are converting the column `a` from first data frame as categorical, you need do the same for second data frame. You can do it as following-

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['a', 'b'])
df['a']=pd.Categorical([],[0, 1])

new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[0,1,1,1,0,0],'b':[1,1,8,4,0,0]})
new_df['a'] = pd.Categorical(new_df['a'],[0, 1])

df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this helps.